# Uncaught TypeError：Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a dynamic content using ajax:

```
$(function(){
   $('#loadFeed').bind('click',function(){ 
        $.getJSON('getData.php', function(json) {
            var output="<ul id='feedsList'>";

            for(var i=json.posts.length-1;i>=json.posts.length-31;i--){
                output+="<li class='post'>";
                output+="<div class='text' id='"+json.posts[i].id+"'>"+json.posts[i].shortmsg+"</div>";         
                output+="</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>"
            $(output).appendTo('.posts');
    });
  });
});
```

The html codes:

```
<div class="posts">
    <!--dynamic content here-->
</div>
```

I wanna click the short text, then the text will expand to show the entire text.The code to implement it was:

```
<script>
$(".posts").on("click", ".text",function(){
        var thisID = this.id; 
        $.getJSON('getData.php', function(json) {  
            alert(thisID);
            $(this).replaceWith("<div class='long_text'>"+json.posts[thisID-1].msg+"<div>"); 
        });
});
</script>
```

The error was

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined .
```

I don't know why it recognizes msg as undefined. I defined msg in my getData.php just as what I did to the id, shortmsg. Here is my getData.php:

```
<?php

        // Connecting, selecting database
        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root')
            or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('my_db') or die('Could not select database');

        // Get Data
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM feed ORDER BY feed.userID ASC';

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

        //create json format text from posts
        $json=array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $post=array('id'=>$row['userID'],'avatar'=>$row['avatar'],'postType'=>$row['postType'],'msg'=>$row['msg'],'shortmsg'=>$row['shortmsg'],'title'=>$row['title'],'type'=>$row['type'],'pic'=>$row['pic'],'link'=>$row['link']);
            array_push($json,$post);
        }

        //display it to the user
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo "{\"posts\":".json_encode($json)."}";

        // Closing connection
        mysql_close($link);

        return $row;

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the json respone? Try `console.log (json)` inside the success callback.

Comment: We would have to see the php and/or json as this is an issue with the format of your json response. It doesn't have a `msg` property where you expect it to.

Comment: @Vega Thanks! I knew why the error happened. The json response showed that post[102], but the thisID-1 could be bigger than 102!

Comment: @Vega But why would the length of posts be less than the largest id?